# Is there a way to rewrite this query to work as an SQL view

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have managed to write the below query, which works great. My problem is that I am using it a bunch of times and I think it warrants its own view, but when I have phpmyadmin create the view for me, queries that used to take 0.0060 sec now take 6.2094 sec.

My Query:

```
SELECT tr.uuid, tr.creator,
(
    SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(name)
    FROM tags as t1
    WHERE t1.uuid = tr.uuid and t1.type = "name"
    GROUP BY t1.uuid
) as names,
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name)
    FROM tags as t2
    WHERE t2.uuid = tr.uuid and t2.type = "tag"
    GROUP BY t2.uuid
) as tags

FROM `tags` as tr
```

phpMyAdmin's Conversion:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `textagname` AS 
select 
`tr`.`uuid` AS `uuid`,
`tr`.`creator` AS `creator`,
(
    select group_concat(`t1`.`name` separator ',') AS `GROUP_CONCAT(name)` 
    from `tags` `t1` 
    where ((`t1`.`uuid` = `tr`.`uuid`) and (`t1`.`type` = 'name')) 
    group by `t1`.`uuid`
) AS `names`,
(
    select group_concat(`t2`.`name` separator ',') AS `GROUP_CONCAT(name)`
    from `tags` `t2` 
    where ((`t2`.`uuid` = `tr`.`uuid`) and (`t2`.`type` = 'tag')) 
    group by `t2`.`uuid`
) AS `tags` 
from `tags` `tr`
```

Any ideas as to how I can make my view more time efficient?

ps: Here is the `tags` table structure:

```
Column   Type         Null  Default  Comments
-------  -----------  ----  -------  ------------------
uuid     varchar(36)  No             key of texture
name     varchar(64)  No             tag name
creator  varchar(36)  Yes   NULL     creator of the tag
type     varchar(36)  No             name, or tag
```

Comment: What's the `names` subquery supposed to be doing?  You don't appear to be using it (except to multiply up the number of results).

Comment: What I'm attempting to do with the query is generate a table that is the UUID of each texture with a list of CSV for the texture's names and its tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really explain why your query got slower when converted into a view by phpMyAdmin, but I would try the following query instead:

```
SELECT
  uuid,
  creator,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE type WHEN 'name' THEN name END) AS names,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE type WHEN 'tag'  THEN name END) AS tags
FROM tags
WHERE type IN ('name', 'tag')
GROUP BY
  uuid,
  creator
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Andriy. Changing my search query to use a new view based on this query, and rewriting the rest of it not using any joins, saved nearly 6 seconds on every search!